# Jinja no renderiza bloque

Tags: python, html5, flask

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con **Flask**. Para incluir algunas dependencias que no son comunes a todas las plantillas html he creado, en el archivo **base.html**, un bloque llamado **dependencies**. Sin embargo, no logro que se renderice.

Este el el código de **base.html**:

```
Jinja2
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Fichador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js') }}"></script>
    {% block dependencies %}

    {% endblock dependencies %}
</head>
<body>
 ...
```

Por otro lado, tengo esta otra plantilla, que extiende el contenido de base.html:
**register.html**

```
Jinja2
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block dependencies %}
    <script>console.log("Hola, mundo");</script>
{% endblock dependencies %}


{% block header %}
    <h1>
        {% block title %}Registro{% endblock title %}
    </h1>
{% endblock header %}
```

He puesto un `console.log("Hola, mundo")` como prueba, pero no funciona. El resto de la página se renderiza bien. Hay más bloque abajo, como el contenido o scrips adiconales al final de la página, y todo se carga sin problema. Sin embargo, las dependencias, no hay manera.

He probado también creando un bloque head que envuelva todo el `<head></head>` de base.html, para luego ampliarlo en register.html con:

```
Jinja2
{% block header %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script>console.log("Hola, mundo");</script>
{% endblock header %}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Será que el cierre ha de ser solo `{% endblock %}`, sin poner el nombre del bloque?

Comment: En teoría, se puede. Según la [Jinja Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#named-block-end-tags). Me acabo de dar cuenta de que el problema era que estaba usando el debugger de Visual Studio Code y, por algún motivo, no actualiza los cambios hechos en las plantillas. He cerrado el programa y abierto el servidor en la terminal, y se ha solucionado. Luego he probado otra vez para estar seguro.

Comment: Ok. En ese caso puedes optar por borrar la pregunta (si crees que el problema no va a pasarle a nadie más) o escribir tú mismo una respuesta (si crees que puede ser útil a otros). Pasado un tiempo incluso puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era que estaba corriendo el servidor con Visual Studio Code y éste no estaba actualizando los cambios hechos en las plantillas. Al correr el servidor desde la terminal se ha arreglado.

Al utilizar el debugger de Flask de Visual Studio Code, los cambios hechos en base.html sí aparecen, no así los cambios en regiter.html que están dentro de bloques que extienden la plantilla base. Al menos en mi caso.